# Grunt: How do I watch multiple directories to compile scss files?

Tags: gruntjs

I'm using Magento and I'm working on a project where `.scss` files are in multiple directories.

I was hoping to use the node module grunt-compass-multiple so that I could achieve this but so far I'm not having any luck.

Anyone have any ideas how I can watch multiple directories simultaneously and compile any of them if they change?

This is my current grunt file:

'use strict';

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    compass: {
      dist: {
    options: {
      sassDir: 'scss',
      cssDir: 'css'
    }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      css: {
    files: '**/*.scss',
    tasks: ['compass']
      }
    }

//compassMultiple: { 

    // multiple option provides you to compile multi sassDir. 
//    all: {
//      options: {
//        multiple: [
//          {
//          sassDir: 'scss',
//          cssDir: 'css'
//          },{
//          sassDir: '../../barclays/default/scss',
//          cssDir: '../../barclays/default/css'
//          }
//        ]
//      }
//    }
//  }

  });

 // grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-compass-multiple');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.registerTask('default',['watch', 'compass']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**grunt-compass-multiple** does exactly what you need.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-compass-multiple

```
grunt.initConfig({

  compassMultiple: {
    options : {
      // if you need, you can set options.
      environment: 'production',
      outputStyle: 'compressed',
      javascriptsDir: './js',
      imagesDir: './image',
      fontsDir: './font',
      importPath: './css/framework',
      relativeAssets: true,
      time: true
    },


    // multiple option provides you to compile multi sassDir.
    all: {
      options: {
        multiple: [
          {
          sassDir: 'page/css/cmn/',
          cssDir: '../static/page/css/cmn/'
          },{
          sassDir: 'page/css/orgn/scss',
          cssDir: '../static/page/css/orgn/'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

From : https://github.com/yoheiMune/grunt-compass-multiple

Comment: Yeah I see that, can you see what I need to do to my grunt file to get it to work?